# How to remove duplicate MySQL records (but only leave one)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-delete

How to remove duplicate MySQL records (but only leave one)

Hello everyone, I have a problem, I have several records with the same ID and I would like to eliminate the duplicate records but leaving only one. Any ideas with a mysql statement?

I have this statement to see the records and the number of duplicates but it doesn't work for me when I use a delete:

```
SELECT 
    email, 
    COUNT(email)
FROM
    contacts
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1;
```

I use this statement but it only removes a single duplicate record:

```
DELETE FROM wp_options  WHERE option_id=5 limit 1;
```

Any way to do it massively?

Update: I am using this statement but it eliminates all duplicate records without leaving one:

```
DELETE FROM xhi_options
WHERE  option_id IN (SELECT option_id
                FROM   (SELECT option_id
                        FROM   xhi_options
                        GROUP  BY option_id
                        HAVING COUNT(option_id) > 1) AS T)
```

Comment: Can you include the full table structure for `contacts`?  Is there any column(s) which can differentiate duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to keep the row with the lowest id value

```
DELETE e1 FROM contacts e1, contacts e2 WHERE e1.id > e2.id AND e1.email = e2.email;
```

this an example link [link 1](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/5601ac81eadd21d9a24ba7283e53066e/)

or you can change `>` to `<` for keep the highest id

```
DELETE e1 FROM contacts e1, contacts e2 WHERE e1.id < e2.id AND e1.email = e2.email;
```

this an example link [link 2](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/c4e21ad47d901e7504caee02ba6f203d/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect for me, create an auto-incrementing field in the table and use your statement

Answer (score 0):

In your delete statement you use `limit 1` option, it means that you will delete only one record with this statement.

Try to fix your code like

```
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_id=5 limit (dupl_rec_count - 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? IIRC the `LIMIT` clause does not allow expressions.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I wrote `limit (dupl_rec_count - 1)` as an example because I don't know the actual number of records, of course he should pass a single value